# App targeted for both iPad and iPhone; removing iPad component pre-release

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, device

I'm about to release an app that I have been working on for quite some time and is has currently been built to target both iPhone and iPad. The app has both iPhone and iPad storyboards and various device specific code and views. I now wish to remove the iPad references and release the app targeted for iPhone only.

Can a project be changed in this way without too much difficulty and what are the potential complications that may arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the device target in Xcode to just iPhone, then verify the build runs in the iPhone simulator window on the iPad. You can also check the bundle plist to verify that UIDeviceTarget contains only 1, not 1 and 2.

If you want to remove the iPad resources, click on your storyboard (or other files), check the properties pane, and uncheck the target. This will stop the file from being copied into the app bundle.

Comment: Ok great, this sounds fairly straight forward. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In this image you can see **Devices** is selected for `iPhone` only. You can change it from here.

[image]